# Retrieve battery uptime for android

Tags: android, battery

Is there a way to retrieve the the amount of time since the battery has been charged?

It doesn't appear like there is a way to do so with `BatteryManager`, but they show it to you in the settings.  I see it here [source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Settings.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/settings/BatteryInfo.java;h=1cbe47f988a7478c9fe65c10307448fbf7290dd7;hb=HEAD) , but it doesn't appear like there is a way to grab it. Any help?

Comment: where do you see the time since the battery was last charged in that source?

Comment: I think it does it around the code at around line 56 and around line 196

Comment: and is there anything you see in this code that makes you think that a/ it displays the time since last charge b/ it is an information you don't have access to?

Comment: @user2672165 : why are you editing (for trivial spelling issue) a question that was not touched in the last 3.5 years?

Comment: (there are IBatteryStats and IPowerManager, but apparently they are not used?)

Comment: @njzk2: You are correct that it is really trivial. Is there a way I can propose some kind of automatic spell checker? Can it be proposed on meta? I don't know if google will find this question anyway?

Comment: @njzk2: It seems google is able to find it anyway. You are right then there is no real point in fixing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a broadcast receiver for [ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED), and keep track of the last time it was broadcast.

Comment: but I would like it to grab the correct time even the first time the app is installed and ran